# How to fix $injector:unpr Unknown Provider Error in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting the following error:

> [Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider
>
> Unknown provider: _planetsProvider <- _planets <- SearchController](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/unpr?p0=_planetsProvider%20%3C-%20_planets%20%3C-%20SearchController)

.API get request is working fine and my SearchController.js is also triggered, but I'm still getting the error above. I have tried almost all suggestions from StackOverflow and official document. How can I fix it?

### Here's my code: ([Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/WRh3z5HTGby6nT1G8ovi?p=preview))

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config( function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', { templateUrl: '/views/home.html',
                                controller: 'HomeController' })
      .when('/login', { templateUrl: '/views/login.html',
                                controller: 'LoginController' })
                               
      .when('/search',  { templateUrl: '/views/search.html',
                                controller: 'SearchController',
                                resolve:{
                                    _planets: function(myService)
                                    {
                                        console.log("asdas");
                                        return myService.getRequestForPlanets();

                                    }
                                }
                            })
                                
      });
```

SearchController.js

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('SearchController', function($scope, myService, _planets, $rootScope) {
    $scope.message = 'This is Show orders screen';
    $scope.planets=_planets;
    console.log(_planets);
});
```

myService.js

```
angular.module('myApp').service('myService', function($http, $rootScope, $location, $q)
{   
    $rootScope.loading = false; 

    this.getRequestForPlanets=function()
    {
        $rootScope.loading = true;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('https://swapi.co/api/planets')
        .then(function(response){
            $rootScope.loading = false;
            console.log(response.data.results);
           deferred.resolve(response.data.results);
        })
        .catch(function(response){
          deferred.reject(response);
        });
        
        return deferred.promise;
        
    }

});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCss.css">
 


</head>
<body  ng-app="myApp">
 <!-- ng-controller="myController" -->
 <div class="spinner" ng-show="loading">
  <div class="loader" ></div>
</div>


<div ng-view></div>

<section class="imgDiv">
    <div  class="container-fluid">
        <!-- <img src="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg" style="width: 100%;"> -->
        <div class="sn_scroll_btn slideInDown ">
           <img src="images/scroll.png" alt="" class="test">
       </div>
    </div>
</section>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/LoginController.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/SearchController.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="services/myService.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/HomeController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: edit: If you can create a fiddle illustrating this, that would help get this questions answered

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/WRh3z5HTGby6nT1G8ovi?p=preview

Comment: Are you sure about these lines? $scope.planets=_planets;
    console.log(_planets);

Comment: where is this _planets injected service coming from? have you missed to include any script tag in html file?

Comment: @Rakesh Burbure - I have followed below link to use resolve property in app.js https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Based on the plnkr link you provided: https://plnkr.co/edit/WRh3z5HTGby6nT1G8ovi?p=preview

Your controller is being instantiated twice, once in your routes, in `app.js` here:

```
.when('/search',  { templateUrl: '/views/search.html',
                        controller: 'SearchController',
                        ...
```

and again in your view in `search.html` here:

```
<div ng-controller="SearchController">
<p>{{message}}</p>
...
```

Since the `SearchController` has already been injected into the app by your routes, the second time it's instantiated in the view, it throws the `Unknown Provider` error.

If you remove `ng-controller="SearchController"` from `search.html` it should fix the issue that you're having.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's working fine. SIlly mistake !. I thought I am doing some mistake in "resolve" property in app.js. But it's ng-controller. Thanks a lot.